# Python: Using len to isolate the single element case

Tags: python

This question is from codewars: Sum without highest and lowest number
Objective is to sum the array without the maximum and minimum number.
There are also checks on empty array, single element array, 2 element array and multiple element array.
By doing the test, there is a problem on the single element with the code below.

```
def sum_array(arr):
    output = 0
    high = 0
    low = 0
    if arr == None or '':
        return 0
    if len(arr) == 1:
        output = arr
    else:
        for i in arr:
            high = max(arr)
            low = min(arr)
            output = sum(arr) - high - low
    return output
```

Output:

Fixed Tests
None or Empty
(2 of 2 Assertions)

**Only one Element
[3] should equal 0
[-3] should equal 0**

Only two Element
(2 of 2 Assertions)

Real Tests
(4 of 4 Assertions)

Comment: You assign the output to the array if it's a single element. But that single element is also the maximum, and the minimum. Since both minimum and maximum have to be discarded, you need to remove that single element, leaving zero.

Comment: The for loop is unnecessary: you're not using `i`, and doing the same calculation multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question right..
For single element high & low are same.
thus
len(arr)==1 just return output instead of updating output to arr.

Answer (score 0):

Following what @9769953 said the single element array should return 0. You're also not using i so the for loop is not serving any purpose.

```
def sum_array(arr):
    output = 0
    high = 0
    low = 0
    if len(arr) == 0 or len(arr) == 1:
        output = 0
    else:
        high = max(arr)
        low = min(arr)
        output = sum(arr) - high - low
    return output
```

Comment: There is an array, thus i used the for i in arr in the else loop
{ 6, 2, 1, 8, 10 } => 16
{ 1, 1, 11, 2, 3 } => 6

I tried to remove the for i in arr and got an error
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the requirements. But if I understood your question correctly, this are the requirements:

- If the list is None: `return 0`
- If the list is empty: `return 0`
- If the list contains only one element: `return 0`
- If the list contains at least two elements: `return sum(arr) - max(arr) - min(arr)`

```py
def sum_array(arr):
    if arr is None or not arr or len(arr) == 1: return 0

    return sum(arr) - max(arr) - min(arr)
```

---

**Input**

```py
x = [1, 2]
y = []
z = None
k = [1, 2]
t = [1, 2, 3]
```

**Output**

```bash
0
0
0
0
2
```

Comment: *max(arr)* is O(n) expensive.